# How can I encapsulate composition of Lazy Swift Functions?

Tags: swift, functional-programming, composition

I need a range of functions which will work on an Array of strings to produce other arrays of strings...

Say I start with:

```
let animals = ["ant", "bear", "cat"]
```

Some functions will increase the elements in the array.  For example:

```
extension String {
  func double() -> [String] {
    print("double")
    return [self, self]
  }
}

print( animals.flatMap { $0.double() } )
//double
//double
//double
["ant", "ant", "bear", "bear", "cat", "cat"]
```

and some will reduce the number of elements.  For example:

```
extension String {
  func endsIn(_ endString: String) -> Bool {
    print("endsIn")
    return hasSuffix(endString)
  }
}

print( animals.filter  { $0.endsIn("t") } )
//endsIn
//endsIn
//endsIn
//["ant", "cat"]
```

I want to compose these functions and because the domain of possibilities is large, I want to keep everything lazy which I can do:

```
let lazyComposition = animals
  .lazy
  .flatMap { $0.double() }
  .filter  { $0.endsIn("t") }

for x in lazyComposition {
  print(">>>>>>>>>>> \(x)")
}
//double
//endsIn
//  >>>>>>>>>>> ant
//endsIn
//  >>>>>>>>>>> ant
//double
//endsIn
//endsIn
//double
//endsIn
//  >>>>>>>>>>> cat
//endsIn
//  >>>>>>>>>>> cat
```

I'd like to encapsulate this function composition.
I think I'm nearly there with:

```
extension Array where Element == String {
  func combined() -> AnySequence<[String]> {

    return AnySequence<[String]> { () -> AnyIterator<[String]> in
      var iterator = self
        .lazy
        .flatMap { $0.double() }
        .filter  { $0.endsIn("t") }

      return AnyIterator {
        return iterator.next()    // #ERROR#
      }
    }
  }
}

for x in animals.combined() {
  print(">>>>>>>>>>> \(x)")
}
```

but I get an error on the line marked #ERROR#: Value of type 'LazyFilterCollection < FlattenCollection < LazyMapCollection < Array < String > , [String] > > > ' has no member 'next'

Any help fixing this appreciated.
Or alternatively suggesting other ways to achieve this.
Thanks
Adahus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `Sequence` or `Collection` cannot be used as an `Iterator`, so this part of your code is so confusing:

```
  var iterator = self
    .lazy
    .flatMap { $0.double() }
    .filter  { $0.endsIn("t") }
```

The local variable `iterator` is a `Collection` (specifically it's `LazyFilterCollection <...>` as you get in the error message), not an `Iterator`.

Second, `AnySequence` or `AnyIterator` takes Element type for its generic parameter.

With two things above fixed, you can write something like this:

```
extension Array where Element == String {
    func combined() -> AnySequence<String> {

        return AnySequence<String> { () -> AnyIterator<String> in // <- specify Element type as `String`
            var iterator = self
                .lazy
                .flatMap { $0.double() }
                .filter  { $0.endsIn("t") }
                .makeIterator() // <- make `Iterator` from `Collection`

            return AnyIterator {
                return iterator.next()
            }
        }
    }
}

let animals = ["ant", "bear", "cat"]

for x in animals.combined() {
    print(">>>>>>>>>>> \(x)")
}
```

Output:

```
double
endsIn
>>>>>>>>>>> ant
endsIn
>>>>>>>>>>> ant
double
endsIn
endsIn
double
endsIn
>>>>>>>>>>> cat
endsIn
>>>>>>>>>>> cat
```